# How to mock super method by MockK

Tags: android, mocking, mockk

Assuming we have Activity.onCreate() like this

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun doSomething() {}

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

I want to use MockK to verify if `onCreate()` is invoked, then `doSomething()` is invoked too. However I don't know how to mock the `super.onCreate()` method.

Do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see at https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/607 it seems currently unsupported - or not working.

The issue shows the *Mockito* way of solving this.